# Is it safe for an android app targeting below API 23 to ask permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Android if an app is targeting below api 23 and running on api level 23. The permissions are automatically granted by android at install time, but the user can later on go to Settings-> apps -> myapp-> permissions and deny the permissions.

In that case it appears that I can use

```
 android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker
```

To check for permissions.

If permissions are not granted then

is it safe to ask for permissions using regular methods of API 23 despite the target is under api level 23 ?

MoreInfo: I am using compileSdkVersion 23 and  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: No, I don't think it's going to work. Below level 23 the only way to request permissions remains to declare them in the manifest. Btw below level 23, the user is not able to deny permissions in the settings

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion. If you are using lower then 23 in buildToolsVersion, it will not ask for runtime permissions even if you run the app on Android device of API 23.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API 23, then you'll be able to run the permission checking code on API 23 devices. However you may get an error when doing so on lower API devices because those methods don't exist.

If you are using `AppCompatActivity` instead of a regular `Activity` then you don't need to check your API version before making those calls.